# Downloading and running Jenkins in Docker

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile

The following is taken from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/.
I am working behind proxy.
The last statement *RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.24.7 docker-workflow:1.26"*
is not working. What would be the solution.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.289.3-lts-jdk11
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
       ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \
       software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
       $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.24.7 docker-workflow:1.26"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http_proxy and https_proxy variables like in usual Linux shell environment. Try to add something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy=http://proxy.company.com:8080 \
    https_proxy=https://proxy.company.com:443 \
    no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,company.com
```

This should help you to enable uncletall's answer

Comment: Thanks, As he was able to download updates and install docker I assumed that the proxy part was at least working... but I have added it to my answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jenkins-plugin-cli as it does not support a proxy. The deprecated method still works. Last time I tried I gave up and reverted the the old method of setting the proxy environment variables and adding `RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt`

See: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/1005

I have elaborated and added the proxy configuration and using the deprecated install-plugins.sh

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.289.3-lts-jdk11
USER root
ENV http_proxy=http://proxy.company.com:8080 \
    https_proxy=https://proxy.company.com:443 \
    no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,company.com
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
       ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \
       software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
       $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
/usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh docker-workflow docker-workflow blueocean
```

Comment: But how to run this with proxy option. RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins-plugin-cli uses Java inside the docker. So you need to add proxy for & SSL Cert config for the JAVA separately.

For adding JAVA proxy, I found out that, using JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is a better way than JAVA_OPTS.

In you Dockerfile first add Proxy Options

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS "-Dhttps.proxyHost=123.123.123.123
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyHost=123.123.123.123
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
```

Also you would need to add your Intermediate Certificate to cacerts inside the Docker

Obtain your certificate that is used in your proxy and add this line:

```
RUN keytool -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts  -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias proxycert  -file proxy_cert.crt
```

Here the important part is the path of your JAVA_HOME, in my case I prefered to use the absolute path (/opt/java/openjdk/) though it is better to use $JAVA_HOME.